# Any good reason for Ruby to have == AND eql? ? (similarly with to_a and to_ary)

Tags: ruby, methods

I know eql? is used by Hashes to see if an object matches a key`*`, and you do

```
def ==(rb)
```

if you want to support the == operator, but there must be a good reason that Hashes don't use == instead. Why is that? When are you going to have definitions for == and eql? that are *not* equivalent (e.g. one is an alias to the other) ?

Similarly, why have to_ary in addition to to_a?

This question came up in response to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766712/make-an-object-behave-like-an-array-for-parallel-assignment-in-ruby/768201#768201) someone gave me on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766712/make-an-object-behave-like-an-array-for-parallel-assignment-in-ruby).

`*` Of course, a Hash also assumes eql? == true implies that the hashes codes are equal.

Also, is it basically a terribly idea to override equal? ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between equal?, eql?, ===, and ==?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know the reasoning for this particular choice in ruby, but I'll just point out that equality is a difficult concept.

Common Lisp, for example has eq, eql, equal, equalp, and for that matter =

It can be very useful to be able to tell the difference between two references to the same object, two different objects of the same type with the same value, two objects with the same value but of different types, etc.  How many variations make sense depends on what makes sense in the language.

If I recall it correctly (I don't use ruby), rubys predicates are implementing three of these cases

== is equality of value

eql? is equality of value and type

equal? is true only for the same object

Comment: I can tell you actually thought about this answer. Among the ones that have been posted so far, this one most directly answers the question "why the distinction", which is what I was looking for. The others are more oriented toward "what's the difference". I also like how you point out this is a general language design question. Indeed, there is more than meets the eye when it comes to equality!

Answer (score 14):

== checks if two values are equal, while eql? checks if they are equal AND of the same type.

```
irb(main):001:0> someint = 17
=> 17
irb(main):002:0> someint == 17
=> true
irb(main):003:0> someint.eql? 17
=> true
irb(main):004:0> someint.eql? 17.0
=> false
irb(main):005:0> someint == 17.0
=> true
irb(main):006:0>
```

as you can see above, eql? will also test if both values are the same type. In the case of comparing to 17.0, which equates to false, it is because someint was not a floating point value.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/54/topics/992) mentions that to_a and to_ary (and to_s and to_str , and to_i and to_int) have different levels of strictness. For example,

```
17.to_s
```

makes sense,

```
17.to_str
```

doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That explains some of the reasoning, although I'm still not convinced.

Also, I think you meant "makes sense _to Ruby_". To me, it makes very little sense that 17.to_s works but 17.to_str does not.

Comment: to_s/to_a/to_f/to_i are all explicit conversions.  to_str/to_ary/to_int are all implicit conversions.  For example, I have a URI library I wrote.  My URI class implements to_str because if I have a method that takes a URI in String form as a parameter, I don't want to have to explicitly convert my URI object into a String before passing it as a parameter.  The to_str method allows me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no to_ary method for the Hash class (no to_a), but for the Array class, to_a and to_ary have different behavior :

to_a :

> Returns self. If called on a subclass of Array, converts the receiver to an Array object.

to_ary :

> Returns self.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above more that answer about `eql?` but here is something on `to_a` and `to_ary`.
In Ruby's duck-typing scheme, objects can be converted two ways--loosely and firmly. Loose conversion is like saying:
Can `foo` *represent* itself as an array (`to_a`). This is what `to_a`, `to_s`, `to_i` and other single letter ones are for. So a String can represent itself as an array, so it implements `to_a`. Firm conversion says something very different: Is `foo` a string (`to_ary`). Note that this is not wheather the class of `foo` is String, but whether foo and strings are *interchangeable*--whether anywhere a string is expected a foo could be logically used. The example in my Ruby book is of a Roman numeral class. We can use a Roman numeral anywhere we could use a positive integer, so Roman can implement `to_int`.
Classes that have an *are interchangeable* relationship need to implement firm conversion, while loose is for almost all classes. Make sure not to use firm conversion where loose is right--code built into the interpreter will severely misunderstand you and you'll end up with bugs comparable to C++'s `reinterpet_cast<>`. Not good.