# Why does Ruby hashes use eql? and not ==

Tags: ruby, hash

I see so many notions of equality in Ruby.

```
==
eql?
===
equal?
```

And all of them have different semantics. For me there ought to be just 2 of them, one is reference equality and other is value equality. I don't see why Ruby needed `eql?` and `===`.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770418/any-good-reason-for-ruby-to-have-and-eql-similarly-with-to-a-and-to-ary) which says that the distinction is for just the value and the value and type.

Specifically, I don't understand why `Hash` would need to check for type as well (which usually we test in the `==` method itself)

Comment: It seems you already know the distinction between `==` and `eql?`. I suggest you simplifying your question so that it only focuses on why `Hash` uses `eql?`, not `==`.

Comment: Yep. Doesn't the questions already asks specifically about hashes? Suggest me an edit in case you think I can simply the question.

Comment: What is `#==`? Isn't that just a comment?

Comment: @sawa. You are right. I mistook it with the case equality operator. I'll correct my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hash` requires its keys must support `eql?` because it needs the hash code internally.

For example, `1 == 1.0` is true, while `1.eql? 1.0` is false. `1` and `1.0` obviously have different hash codes, so they can't be treated as equivalent keys in a `Hash`.

Comment: Yes. And then `Hash` should just use the hash method and not the equals method. Is it for efficiency reason that hash needed notion of equality and then a notion of getting a hash?
Because I can just ask for the objects hash and then use it. In case of `1` and `1.0` they will be different and I won't hash them to the same key.

Comment: If you agree `1` and `1.0` should be different keys, then you agree that they are not *equal* in this situation, right? So you are not comparing them using `==`, why not let `eql?` do its appropriate job?

Comment: No, you cannot use the hash to determine equality. That would negate the whole purpose of the hash. A hash maps a larger input space to a smaller output space. Specifically, in case of Ruby's `hash` method, it maps an infinite number of objects to a finite number of `Fixnum`s. This means that, per the Pigeonhole Principle, there are infinitely many objects which have the same hash but are not equal. Ergo, you cannot determine from equal hashes that two objects are equal, you can only determine from unequal hashes that two objects are unequal.

Comment: (This has nothing to do with Ruby or even programming, BTW, this is just basic high school math.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag I understand how hash works. My logic is like this: `1` and `1.0` have unequal hash codes => they shouldn't be the same keys in a hash => they shouldn't be compared using `==` here. This is what you mean by *determine from unequal hashes that two objects are unequal*, or I'm lost somewhere?

Comment: Yu, I believe @Jörg was merely pouring cold water on Dhruv's suggestion that hash values alone should be used to determine if two keys are distinct.